# IIS 10 Self Signed Trusted Wildcard Certificate

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, wildcard

I've tried many, many, MANY methods of creating a self signed trusted wild card cert. Chrome keep complaining that it's not valid. Does anyone have THE DEFINITIVE instructions for creating this?

- Windows 10
- IIS 10
- Needs to be wildcard (*.local.com)
- Must be trusted so the browsers don't complain
- Dev environment only

Comment: You want to create a self signed cert, and have it be trusted by all browsers without any further work? This is never going to work, if it did the whole certificate process would be pointless. For browsers to trust your certificate it either needs to come from a trusted certificate authority (so you need to buy a cert), or you need to manually have the browser trust it.

Comment: No, I just need my dev machine to trust it. Just my browser.